# Verify that $\nabla(A\cdot B) = (B\cdot\nabla)A + (A\cdot\nabla)B + B\times(\nabla\times A) + A\times(\nabla\times B)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

I'm trying to verify the following identity
$$\nabla(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}) = (\textbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{A} + (\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{B} + \textbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{A}) + \textbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{B})$$

To make this, I'm using the $BAC-CAB$ expansion of the triple vector product. Then, I get these two equations $ \textbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{B}) =  \nabla(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}) - (\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{B}$ and $ \textbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{A}) =  \nabla(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}) - (\textbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{A}$. Adding these equations I obtained that

$$ 2\nabla(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B}) = (\textbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{A} + (\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{B} + \textbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{A}) + \textbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{B}) $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't really use the "$BAC-CAB$" expansion of the triple vector product as $\nabla$ isn't a vector - it's a vector operator (it may work, but I wouldn't advise it). If you use suffix notation on the terms you tried to expand otherwise, you'll see that you don't actually get $\nabla(\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{B})$ but something similar; after swapping $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ and adding the equations, you do get the desired term.

Comment: But the operator $\nabla$  should satisfy the vector rules and partial differentiation rules. So, could I treat it as vector, not?

Comment: Are $\nabla \cdot \textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{A} \cdot \nabla$ the same thing?

Comment: No, they aren't

Comment: So, do you see the danger in just treating $\nabla$ as a vector, seeing as the order in which you take operations then has a huge effect on what you get? While it is certainly possible to try and keep track of what is the "correct" order of doing things just by thinking if your end result is a vector, tensor, operator etc., in the long run for these types of things it is better to use suffix notation to prove these kind of results, and then it's quite a bit harder to go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \times (\nabla \times B) = \nabla (A \cdot B) - (A \cdot \nabla) B$ only when holding $A$ constant.  Denote this as $\dot \nabla (A \cdot \dot B)$ to show that only $B$ is differentiated.  Do the same for the other identity.

Then, notice that $\nabla (A \cdot B) = \dot \nabla (\dot A \cdot B) + \dot \nabla (A \cdot \dot B)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I only didn't understand why I have to hold A constant (But it works!). Can you explain me better?

Comment: That's an implicit assumption when you write that $A \times (\nabla \times B)$ identity.  The identity *is not true* otherwise.